# Navigation Drawer Header View Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I'm new to Kotlin and not able to understand how we can set the image and header components in the default android navigation drawer.

I found few links on the internet but all are written in Java. I need Kotlin equivalent code.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code for setting up image on navigation drawer using kotlin.

```
val navigationView: NavigationView =  findViewById(R.id.nv)
val header: View = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
val tv: TextView = header.findViewById(R.id.profilename)
val image: ImageView = header.findViewById(R.id.profileImage)
tv.text = "Your_Text"
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image)
```